# Probability density function on uniform distribution

Tags: probability, density-function

> Let $R=\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ~|~ x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 1\}$ be the
>   unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It was stated to me that $\rho$ is the
>   uniform probability on the square $[-1,1]^2$ and that
>   $\rho(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{4}$ if both $|x_1|$ and $|x_2|$ are at most 1
>   and $\rho(x_1,x_2)=0$ otherwise.

I cannot figure out where the values of $1/4$ and $0$ for the $\rho(x_1,x_2)$ are coming from. Any help would be much appreciated. I know that the area of the circle is $\pi$ and the area of the square is $4$ so it seems like it should be a density of $\pi/4$ to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence has nothing  to do with the first. It simply specifies the density function of uniform distribution on the rectangle $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ and the region $R$ does not appear in the second sentence.

Comment: I see. Is that because the total area of the rectangle is 4. So we have to multiply by 1/4 for the normalization so the area is one?

Comment: @MathIsHard Exactly. $\frac 1 4$ comes from the areas of the rectangle.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help